# GLSL component-wise equal comparison

Tags: opengl, vector, comparison, glsl, equals

I'm trying to check if a given pixel in a texture is white, black, or neither. I've decided to use the [equal function described in the OpenGL 4 Reference Pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/equal.xhtml). I believe I'm just having an issue getting the syntax correct.

I am using OpenGL version 4.0.0 and OpenGL Shading Language version 4.00.

Here is the relevant part of my fragment shader code:

```
   //texture 1
   vec4 textureColor1 = texture(texUnit1, textureCoord);
   //texture 2
   vec4 textureColor2 = texture(texUnit2, textureCoord);
   //texture 3 (only contains black and white pixels)
   vec4 textureColor3 = texture(texUnit3, textureCoord);

   vec4 finalTextureColor;

   vec4 whiteColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); //define white
   vec4 blackColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); //define black

   if (bvec equal(textureColor3, whiteColor)){ //if texture 3 pixel is white
        finalTextureColor = textureColor1;
   } else if (bvec equal(textureColor3, blackColor)){  //if texture 3 pixel is black
        finalTextureColor = textureColor2;
   } else { //not black or white
        finalTextureColor = mix(textureColor1, textureColor2, 0.5);
   }

   color = finalTextureColor;
```

Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
ERROR: 0:101: 'bvec' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:101: 'equal' : syntax error syntax error
```

I know that my texture data is getting correctly passed to the fragment shader because I can say `color = textureColor1` or `color = textureColor2` or `color = textureColor3`, all of which display the appropriate texture on the 3D object.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think that you want a component-wise `equal`. `equal` returns a boolean vector (that's what `bvec` stands for) but you want a single boolean. So just use `if(textureColor3 == whiteColor)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bvec` is the return type of the `equal` function.  You get a vector of booleans to tell you which components are equal.  If you just want to compare the entire color, then use the equality operator `==`.